# What alternatives to the make command are able to detect file changes on other criteria than timestamp?

Tags: build-process, makefile

What alternatives to the make command are able to detect file changes on other criteria than timestamp?

So far I have only found Rant ( http://rant.rubyforge.org/ ) which is able to detect file changes based on MD5 checksums instead of file modification times.

Are there others?

Ideally I would be able to specify an external command that is used to detect file changes (in that case I would be able to compare local file checksums to checksums of remote files on S3 for example).

Comment: Also found this one: https://github.com/apenwarr/redo

Comment: Also found this comparison of make commands: http://biowiki.org/MakeComparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are looking something like **[makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/) signature methods**. Options for makepp are:

```
exact_match
target_newer
md5
c_compilation_md5
shared_object
xml
default (= target_newer)
```

They are all described [here](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/2.0/makepp_signatures.html)